# is there no more new chrome extension are allowed to publish for chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am a bit confused... I was reading the tutorial for developing chrome extensions. But once I reach the step where to release it, I saw the developer console this message.

Does it means that my chrome extension will no longer available for chrome browser on any other OS than Chrome OS?

[image]

Comment: Extensions are not apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) are not [Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions). The change in policy applies to Chrome Apps, not Chrome Extensions.

Your Chrome extension will be available for users of Google Chrome on all OS platforms where Chrome supports extensions (i.e. [not on Android](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/faq)).